# Least number of comparisons to identify 6 numbers with values from 1 to 6 (without repetition)

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Variabled $x_1, \dots, x_6$ have hidden, distinct integer values from [$1,\dots,6$]. How to identify each variable's value with minimum number of comparison operations?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We prefer to see some effort from the asker, not least because it helps us know what level to pitch an answer at.

Comment: What are the possible results of each comparison?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list), the minimum number of comparisons needed to sort 6 numbers is 10. The lower bound follows from the usual decision tree argument.